# Can I refer to a dictionary's key name with a variable, from within a view

Tags: python, web2py

I have a bunch of data generated within a controller which I want to access programmatically, using a loop.

The dictionary entries have keys "Point1", "Point2", "Point3" etc,

If I want to populate a table on my view with them, iteratively, I thought I might be able to use something like:

```
<td>{{="Point{0}".format(407)}}</td>
```

but this doesn't work, it returns the text"Point407"

The following code:

```
<td>{{=Point407}}</td>
```

Works as I'd expect, displaying the contents of dictionary entry "407".

Comment: Why don't you use a list instead?

Comment: take advantage of a controller class here. have the controller code pass to the view exactly what you want. complicated scriptlets are evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like:

```
{{=globals()['Point{0}'.format(407)]}}
```

But it would be much better if your controller returned something like:

```
return dict(points=[point1, point2, ...])
```

And then in the view:

```
{{=points[0]}}
```

Comment: This is almost what I ended up doing. I still created a dictionary (of tuples) in my controller, as that made sense for random key-based access during data processing/generation. I then copy all the values into a list of tuples for passing to the view, which I can access nicely by index. Blender's comment sent me down this path initially.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having this in your controller,

```
def x:
   return {"Point407":1, "Point408":2}
```

Consider a more appropriate structure:

```
def x:
   return {"points": {'407':1, '408':2}}
```

Then you could do this in your view:

```
<td>{{=points.get('407')}}</td>
```